# Angular nesting async ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently developing an application with angular. I reached a very strange problem with the `*ngFor` template directive:

```
<div *ngfor="let accountGroup of groupedAccountsList">
    <h3 class="accounts__identifier">
        {{accountGroup.key}}
    </h3>
    <table class="datalist">
        <tr class="datalist__header">
            <th class="datalist__column">
                {{ 'accounts.number' | translate }}
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngfor="let account of accountGroup.accounts" class="datalist__row">
            <td class="datalist__column">
                {{account.accountNumber}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This code does work, when I do subscribe to my observable and do the grouping myself. Actually, is there any way to use the `async` pipe in a nested way?

I tried to use the following code to produce the grouped observable with code, but so far, I've been unlucky to actually subscribe to the nested observable.

```
this.resourceService
    .getAccounts(data.client.id)
    .subscribe(accounts => {
        let hash = {};
        for (let acc of accounts) {
            if (!hash[acc.relationship.id]) {
                hash[acc.relationship.id] = [];
            }
            hash[acc.relationship.id].push(acc);
        }
        this.groupedAccountsList = Object.keys(hash).map(key => {
            return {
                key,
                accounts: hash[key]
            };
        });
    });
```

All the grouping has to be done by custom synchronous code. Something like the following must be possible (IMO)

```
this.groupedAccountsList = this.resourceService
    .getAccounts(data.client.id)
    .flatMap<AccountModel>(o => Observable.from(o))
    .groupBy<string, AccountModel>(o => o.relationship.id)
    .map(o => {
         return {
             key: o.key,
             accounts: o.toArray()
        };
    })
    .toArray()
```

Is there a general mistake in my understanding of observables and RxJS or is the nested async pipe not working?

Cheers

Comment: I don't see any use of the `async` pipe in your code sample. `Observable.prototype.groupBy` is certainly an elegant solution (there is no need to specify the type arguments, BTW)